# Very long startup time on Ubuntu Server (network configuration) on fanless 2 ethernet PC : systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

Tags: networking

I am a new to Unbuntu Server 22.04.2 and I have a very long startup time.

I use a smal fanless I3 PC with 2 ethernet and WIFI. I use only one ethernet.

My first investigation conduct to extract following informations :

At startup I have extract:

```
sudo journalctl -b
Nov 01 12:35:40 hsm3 systemd-timesyncd[630]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Nov 01 12:35:41 hsm3 systemd-networkd-wait-online[668]: Timeout occurred while waiting for network connectivity.
Nov 01 12:35:41 hsm3 systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

I try to change network plan without sucess by adding optional: true:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  version: 2
```

finaly I have found a turn arround solution that not please me. Add a time out ! The command stil create the issue, but I don't wait more than 5 seconds --timeout=5:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1-or-later
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Wait for Network to be Configured
Documentation=man:systemd-networkd-wait-online.service(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Requires=systemd-networkd.service
After=systemd-networkd.service
Before=network-online.target shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --timeout=5
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

But I don't like this "non solution".

Could you help me to solved the root problem ?

Regards to all

---

After updating with version 22.04.03 LTS same results :

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-88-generic x86_64)

:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.


hsm@hsm3:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

logs extraction:

```
Nov 01 18:58:46 hsm3 systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 01 18:58:47 hsm3 systemd-networkd[663]: enp2s0: Gained IPv6LL
Nov 01 18:58:47 hsm3 systemd-timesyncd[627]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Nov 01 18:58:48 hsm3 systemd-networkd-wait-online[664]: Timeout occurred while waiting for network connectivity.
Nov 01 18:58:48 hsm3 systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 01 18:58:48 hsm3 systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 01 18:58:48 hsm3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured.
Nov 01 18:58:48 hsm3 systemd-timesyncd[627]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Nov 01 18:58:48 hsm3 systemd[1]: Starting Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)...
```

I have also a second PC where I have install version 23.10 and same result.

Any other idea ?

Regards

Comment: If you're provided details are accurate; I'll suggest applying security fixes to your system asap. A fully upgraded 22.04 system has reported itself at 22.04.3 for some time now; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/  shows the ISO release date with installed systems upgrading to it before that date.

Comment: `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` is a mere symptom. Focus on the cause `Timeout occurred while waiting for network connectivity` instead.

Comment: Hello,many thanks for your help. but after update, same result. I have a second PC and I have install 23.10 also same result